# Kendo Template shows Raw html when called from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using a Kendo Grid and I have a function which I am using to get some Html to render for one of my colmumns. My code looks like following:

```
{
                        field: "StateString",
                        title: "State",
                        width: "120px",
                        encoded: true,
                        template: '#:GetFaClass(data.StateString)#'
 }
```

Now, when we call this function it looks like following:

```
function GetFaClass(status) {
    if (status == 'Queued') {
        return ('<i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i>')
    }
}
```

Funny enough, it does call the function and return the value but then shows it as text rather than rendering the html. Now, if instead of calling the function, if I hardcode the value like below then it renders fine:

```
{
                        field: "StateString",
                        title: "State",
                        width: "120px",
                        encoded: true,                     
                        template: ('<i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i>')
                    }
```

What may I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to render as HTML you had to change

```
template: '#:GetFaClass(data.StateString)#'
```

to:

```
template: '#=GetFaClass(data.StateString)#'
```

You have to change the colon(":") to an equals ("=")

[source kendo template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview)